# What are the "local" variables in Postman?

Tags: postman

Postman's documentation leaves a lot to be desired. In their [Variables page](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/postman/environments_and_globals/variables) they say:

> The following scopes are available to you:
>
> 1. Global
> 2. Environment
> 3. Local
> 4. Data

There's information about the Global and Environment scopes, and I believe the "Data" scope is the data from a collection run. But what are the "local" variables?

Because I'd love to have a variable that is calculated on the fly, used for the request, and then discarded. Both global and environment variables are persistent.

Comment: Did none of these answers, help? Please mark an answer or respond to as why....thx.

Answer (score 15):

According to the [Postman Quick Reference Guide](https://postman-quick-reference-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cheatsheet.html#local-variables) **local variables** are only available within the request (or collection run) that has set them. So they are used for the request or collection run and then discarded.

**When to use**:

passing data from the pre-request script to the request or tests or between requests.

The behavior is a bit different in Postman vs Collection Runner / Newman, so make sure you understand how they work before using!

**Setting**

```
pm.variables.set('myVariable', MY_VALUE);
```

**Getting**

```
pm.variables.get('myVariable', MY_VALUE);
```

**Removing**

Local variables are automatically removed once the tests have been executed / collection run finished.

Comment: Can I set a local variable in a pre-request script and then access it in the authorization section of the same request? If so, how?

Comment: Just use pm.variables.set and use it like any other variable using the curly braces syntax.

Comment: I tried that. It works in the "param" section of the request, but not in the "authorization" section.

Comment: Please share an example.

Answer (score 1):

Local variables are the one you use in your Tests part. 
You may even use the 'let' declaration as it is coded in javascript ...
ie:

```
let jsonData;
jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
```

or use var for declaration.

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
```

Though, you can erase globals on the fly using

```
pm.environment/global.unset(<variable>)
```

see [here](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/postman/scripts/postman_sandbox_api_reference) for details

Comment: Well, the word "local" doesn't really appear on that page. :) Anyways, I was hoping for a kind of variable that I can use in my request. As far as I can tell, local JS variables can't be used there.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand ... I'm a beginner in javascript (I started to use Postman) but I use 'local' variables in my pre-request and tests scripts and it works fine. Are local JS variables special ? maybe something you need to import ?

Comment: I agree with Vilx and hoped they meant some kind of variable that can be used independently from the environment. But i guess they mean the variables declared using JavaScript. Too bad.

Comment: @A.Joly - So, what I want to do, is to make a pre-request script which does some magical calculations and then appends another parameter to the request body (it's a POST request). Unfortunately the request variable is read-only in pre-request script. Luckily the request body can reference variables like `{{some_variable}}`. There's "global" and "environment" variables that can be used for it (I already use a bunch for switching between environments), and THESE can be affected by the pre-request script.

Comment: Unfortunately they are both pretty global and permanent, while the results of my magical calculation are pretty temporarily.

Comment: ok, I see. indeed, that's a missing feature. However, you still have the possiblity to use a global and delete it after use in order to clean up ... :)